# git: copy folder from remote master

Tags: git

I have git branch and want to rename a directory in the branch with some changes made to it and get the exact copy of the origin folder from master to my branch. How can I achieve the desired branch state shown below?

```
Remote and local master:

folder1
folder2_v1


Current git branch:

folder1
folder2_v1


Desired state on branch:

folder1
folder2_v2 (renamed the folder2_v1 to v2 with some added additional changes)
folder2_v1 (need to pull exact copy from remote/local master)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have that in from of you without messing up with your branches history and nothing committed just so that you can play with it

```
git mv folder2_v1 folder2_v2 # move the directory as you have it
git checkout origin/master -- folder2_v1 # get the directory as it is in in origin (adjust remote name if required)
```

That should do

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your issue, but you can just start your job from the remote, duplicate desired folder then commit the new dir (In order to keep git history) :

```
$ git checkout origin/master 
$ cp -R folder2_v1 folder2_v2
... add your changes
$ git add folder2_v2
$ git commit -m "some comments"
```